# how to run adb shell commands from android code?

Tags: android

I want to run these commands from  java code:

```
adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps, wifi,network 

a broadcast -a android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE --ez enabled true
```

Please help me how to run from Android code.

Comment: so you want to run shell commands?

Comment: yes I want to run shell commands to enable gps

Answer (score 9):

You can use this method to run commands

```
private void runShellCommand(String command) throws Exception {
    Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
    process.waitFor();
}
```

Comment: any idea of this error "java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "adb": error=13, Permission denied" ?

Comment: @HaiHw Have you ever solved that io exception? I'm getting the same thing.

Comment: @EugenioLopez I think it requires rooted device to run.

Comment: No rooted device won't solve the problem @Eugenio Lopez

Comment: @HaiHw  
->  just write the command it self : for example :use "settings put secure location_providers_allowed" instead of  "adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed..."

Answer (score 4):

OK you will be needing `Runtime` class. There is a good tutorial on executing shell commands [here](http://www.learn2crack.com/2014/03/android-executing-shell-commands.html). For a quick answer, try this:

```
String commandToRun = "adb shell settings put secure location_providers_allowed gps, wifi,network a broadcast -a android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE --ez enabled true";
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(commandToRun);
```