# How to wipe application data from another application (Android)

Tags: android, caching, root

I would like to create an application (for an Android rooted device) which remove the cache of another one.

I found [DevicePolicyManager](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/admin/DevicePolicyManager) but the only wipe function is for the entire device..

Do you have any clue ?

Comment: use adb to retreive installed packages. then use "adb shell pm clear my.app.package.name" to clear the data for a package (check this out for more info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731728/how-to-run-adb-shell-commands-from-android-code)

Comment: Thank you, that seems to be the solution :)