# Remove Permissions at runtime

Tags: android, ios, xamarin.forms, permissions

I am trying to make a form where people can toggle notifications on and off. I figured the easiest way to do that would be set the permissions to allow or deny but I can't figure out how to remove the permission once it has been granted.

I am triggering the initial permission request by doing the following in android and not too sure what I will do with iOS as it requests the permissions somewhat automatically.

```
string rec = "android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE";
string reg = "android.c2dm.intent.REGISTRATION";  
ActivityCompat.RequestPermissions(Plugin.CurrentActivity.CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Activity, new string[] { rec, reg },0);
```

I essentially would like a page that has a few Switch controls to enable/disable permissions.

any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks,

Comment: The easiest way to not notify them would be to just not trigger the notification.

Comment: You can use a Switch controls to record the Switch state and then send or not send notifications based on that state

Answer (score 3):

There's no built in method for you to toggle a permission (ie, allow, then disallow), but you *could* do it if your app can run an `adb` command.

To undo a permission:

```
adb shell pm revoke <package_name> <permission_name>
```

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/32683390/6668797

To run an `adb` command within your app, a couple of variations, but all involve:

```
Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("your command")
```

- [how to run adb shell commands from android code?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31731728/how-to-run-adb-shell-commands-from-android-code)
- [Is it possible to execute adb commands through my android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13381828/is-it-possible-to-execute-adb-commands-through-my-android-app)